# how to call php function using <a> anchor tag?

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to call a PHP function within an anchor tag?
I have two links as

```
<a href="frndpf.php">dinesh</a>
<a href="frndpf.php">prashant</a>
```

When I press **dinesh** the function will be call by *parameter dinesh* and when I press **prashant** the function will be call by *parameter prashant.*

Is there any method to do it?

Comment: no. you can LINK to a script that runs the php function, or use an ajax call via javascript to invoke the php indirectly. but PHP runs on the server, and cannot possibly run in a user's browser.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to call a PHP function within an anchor tag

Not directly.

You can specify a URL. That URL can be handled by PHP. The default action for the PHP program that handles that URL can be to call a function (or to examine the query string to determine which function to call).

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like that:

```
 <a href="frndpf.php?action=dinesh">dinesh</a>
 <a href="frndpf.php?action=prashant">prashant</a>
```

frndpf.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'dinesh') {
    ...
}
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'prashant') {
    ...
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
<a href="frndpf.php?param=dinesh">dinesh</a>
<a href="frndpf.php?param=prashant">prashant</a>
```

Than you can use `$_REQUEST['param']` in your script to check its value.

However, php is a server side language and you can't call a php function on client side. You can request a php file to the server and it will elaborate it according to passed parameters.

Answer (score 1):

if you append the values to the links;

```
<a href="frndpf.php?action=dinesh">dinesh</a>
<a href="frndpf.php?action=prashant">prashant</a>
```

when the page reloads, you can pass the value of $_GET["action"] to your function

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a serverside language and is parsed before any code is sent to your browser, so you cant call a PHP function inline with your code. But you can call a new php page from your links like so:

```
<a href="frndpf.php?parameter=dinesh">dinesh</a>
<a href="frndpf.php?parameter=prashant">prashant</a>
```

And then use GET variables to access those parameters in frndpf.php like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['parameter'])){
  echo $_GET['parameter'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a parameter to another page, and then call the function, like

```
<a href="frndpf.php?name=dinesh">dinesh</a>
```

and then use `$_GET['name'];` to get that value, and call the function.