# How to pass arguments to PHP function from anchor link

Tags: php, function, arguments, anchor

Can i pass arguments to a PHP function when user clicks on anchor link i.e.  tag like:

```
<a href="<?php myFunction($a, $b, $c); ?>">Click here</a>
```

and some PHP function in the same document like:

```
<?php
   function myFunction($val1, $val2, $val3)
   {
     echo "<br>You passed: ".$val1.",".$val2.",".$val3;
    }
?>
```

Help me please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296270/how-to-call-php-function-using-a-anchor-tag

Comment: php runs on the server, long before the html page has even reached the client. Your function would be run at the time the page is generated, and then the php code is **GONE**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is server side code and executes there only. It executes before sending output to the requesting client.

```
<a href="<?php myFunction($a, $b, $c); ?>">Click here</a>
```

That will only leave you with an empty `href` attribute, and call `myFunction()` (in server side processing) while doing it. If you want to run a php function on a user event, you need send a request back to your server, listen for the event that occurred on the page requested, and then do your processing there.

For example, your link can look like

```
<a href="/your/page.php?func=myFunction">Click here</a>
```

Then in `/your/page.php`, you can check for the query string in url

```
if(isset($_GET["func"]) && $_GET["func"] === "myFunction") {
    myFunction($a, $b, $c);
}
```

Comment: Can i send some values along with url in <a href="/page/page.php?func=myFunction&val1=54$val2=68&val3=21">Click here</a>

Comment: Yes. You have a `$` that should be a `&`, but other than that, it looks fine. Make sure you not passing sensitive data like this. Another option is to set values in html input fields ex `<input type="hidden" name="var1" value="<?php echo $var1; ?>" />` then post it to the page using your `<form action="/page/page.php" ` and a submit button. Then you can retrieve the same way, but with `$_POST["var1"]`

Answer (score 0):

No. You might try a Javascript function instead, which runs client side, vs. PHP running server side.

Comment: Then how can i call a PHP function from JS without using AJAX??